# CUDA grid stride loop for nested for loop

Tags: cuda

I am using CUDA grid stride loop, the result looks good, but I am not 100% understand why only need do this stride thing to the outer loop, and nothing changes with the inner loop.

```
__global__
void bodyForce(Body *p, float dt, int n) {
  
  int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;


  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
  {
    float Fx = 0.0f; float Fy = 0.0f; float Fz = 0.0f;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++)
    {
      float dx = p[j].x - p[i].x;
      float dy = p[j].y - p[i].y;
      float dz = p[j].z - p[i].z;
      float distSqr = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz + SOFTENING;
      float invDist = rsqrtf(distSqr);
      float invDist3 = invDist * invDist * invDist;

      Fx += dx * invDist3; Fy += dy * invDist3; Fz += dz * invDist3;
    }

    p[i].vx += dt*Fx; p[i].vy += dt*Fy; p[i].vz += dt*Fz;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code appears to be lifted directly from the assessment exercise of the NVIDIA DLI introductory CUDA C++ [course](https://courses.nvidia.com/courses/course-v1:DLI+C-AC-01+V1/info).

If you are taking this course, the grid-stride loop is something you write, in the process of converting the original CPU-only code to one that is GPU accelerated.  So the code is whatever you choose to write.

The reason the grid-stride  loop on the outer for-loop *makes sense* is because the work done on the outer for-loop iterations is **independent**.  The order of calculation does not matter from one iteration to the next, and so this can be easily/trivially parallelized across CUDA threads, and [the grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) is one way to distribute the work of the outer for-loop (in the original CPU-only code) across CUDA threads.

The inner for-loop represents work that is **not** trivially independent across iterations, because one iteration is adding to the result of the previous iteration:

```
  Fx += dx * invDist3; Fy += dy * invDist3; Fz += dz * invDist3;
```

Therefore the distribution of this work across CUDA threads would not have the same trivial/mechanical methodology that was used to parallelize the outer for-loop.

It could be done of course, but that requires teaching the concepts of a parallel reduction across threads, which has not been dealt with at that point in that course.  Therefore a sensible approach is to leave the inner for-loop alone, to be processed by a single thread, per `Body`.

This realization still allows achieving the performance objectives set up in the assessment exercise for that course.

Comment: So the inner for-loop is not paralyzed? If it is not, I am confused about how the distribution works, since these two for-loop are in one kernel and this kernel is called to be operated on the device.

Comment: I mean if the inner for-loop is not paralyzed, how could the device know, because j is starting from 0 not index?

Comment: the inner loop is not parallelized.  Each CUDA thread runs an instance of that loop.

Comment: The reason the inner loop does something "different" per CUDA thread, is because it is using the `i` variable, which is different per CUDA thread.

Comment: no I mean `i`.  `i` varies from one CUDA thread to the next.  `j` proceeds through the same iterations (0..n-1) in each thread.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused again if j is proceeded in each thread, why the inner loop is not parallelized?

Comment: Perhaps we're just getting tripped up by terminology.

Comment: Do you recall the pointer buf and p of this task, buf is float pointer, and p is a pointer for a structure that has 6 elements. I am testing it with cudaMallocManaged both for buf and p, for p, I simply make the size become 6 times, but the result is worse, so I am quite confused which one should be cudaMallocManaged, p or buf?  Thank you.